# Angular app doesn't display on IOS Safari after cleaning cache

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, safari

I am building a web app using AngularJS. When I try to open it in Safari on IOS after cleaning cache I get a blank page. When I use inspect element I see all the html is properly rendered, but nothing is shown on the screen!

It happens only on IOS Safari, not on chrome or any other device.

Thanks in advance to anybody that has an idea about this issue.

Comment: any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Backup your project and then remove components one at a time until it shows up.

I would put this as a comment but I don't have enough rep, sorry!